# Firebase deploy on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-notifications

I create push notification with node.js for my android chatting app project with firebase.
When I deploy my firebase at notification function, I got some error.

This is my index.js
at 38 : 11 and 39:16

```
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${receiver_id}/device_token`).once('value');


                return deviceToken.then(response => 
                {
                const token_id = result.val();
                const payload = 
                {
                                notification:
                                {
                                title: "Friend Request",
                                body: "you have received a new friend request",
                                icon:"default"
                                }
                };

  38.           return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
  39.                               .then(response => 
                                        {
                                            console.log('This was the notification feature.');
                                        });
                });
```

And this is my error

```
Running command: npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint

> functions@ lint C:\Users\Iax\Desktop\NotificationFunction\functions
> eslint .


C:\Users\Iax\Desktop\NotificationFunction\functions\index.js
  38:11  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
  39:16  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Iax\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-21T16_30_37_019Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Having trouble? Try firebase deploy --help
```

can anyone help me ?

Comment: Those are ESLint errors: well, 1 warning and 1 error. Check what "no-nesting" and "always-return" mean here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-promise#promise-rules

Answer (score 1):

It fails because your code has some styling issues and ESLint is showing it.
ESLint checks the code styling according to its config and if there are errors, it exits with non-zero, causing the deploy to stop with error.

You have 2 ways to fix that:

- Fix code styling issues;
- Change ESLint config to ignore it.

As for your code, it can be rewritten this way (I didn't test it though, but it should work the same):

```
const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${receiver_id}/device_token`).once('value');

return deviceToken.then(response => {
    const token_id = result.val();
    const payload = {
        notification:
        {
            title: "Friend Request",
            body: "you have received a new friend request",
            icon:"default"
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload);
}.then(response => {
    console.log('This was the notification feature.');
    return true;
});
```